# iOS: AFNetworking's AFHTTPSessionManager cache policy

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

I have a standard subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager`. I am using the `initWithBaseURL:sessionConfiguration:` initializer by providing the session configuration I need. I am setting the `requestCachePolicy` variable on the configuration with the intention that all requests will follow the given cache policy. However, if I am to check the policy of the request on any of the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` callback methods, it is not set to the value on the configuration. To solve this I need to set the `cachePolicy` variable of the `requestSerializer` of the session manager.

Seems that when AFNetworking is making NSURLRequest objects it is not using the cache policy value set in the session configuration object. That said, what is the reason for setting the cachePolicy on the session configuration as opposed to the requestSerializer ?

Is this a bug or an incomplete feature in AFNetworking 2.0 or I am missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

AFHTTPSessionManager uses cookies to cache requests.

Simply delete cookies.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
```